# Why does free() leaves stuff in memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

I'm trying to understand how malloc-realloc and free works deeply in C.
I've found [this page](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals) and I was able to understand how a chunk is allocated, but I'm not entirely sure how the free function works, because in my test program it leaves some data in memory after free is called.

This is how the memory look before...

```
33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 *q=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 49 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

...and after the free function:

```
33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 *q=112 132 178 223 255 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 49 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have understood that 33 is the chunk size stored in the chunk header, but I can't understand what the numbers after "q" means when the memory is freed.

Q is the address returned by the malloc.

Thanks!

Comment: When the memory is freed, the program is free to allocate that memory to something else.  It has no obligation to waste CPU cycles clearing out the data.

Comment: *and after the free function* – After `free(q);` you have no business looking at that memory through `q`. After `free(q);` the pointer `q` holds an invalid pointer value and dereferencing an invalid pointer value has undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: The question does not ask why `free` does not clear out data. It asks why `free` writes new data into the space.

Comment: @Swordfish: The OP does have business looking at the memory. They are investigating the implementation of `free`. While the C standard does not define the behavior, it does not prohibit people from investigating the C implementation in any way they desire. The lack of definition by the C standard does not nullify other causes of behavior, such as the code that implements `malloc` and `free`, and it reasonable to investigate it in the same way it is reasonable for a person to learn how a machine works by disassembling and poking at it, even if that voids the manufacturer’s warranty.

Comment: After you release the memory, you have given up all rights to it, and the implementation may do as it pleases with the space.  It may legitimately make it so that an attempt to read or write to any of the previously allocated data generates a segmentation fault.  (It usually doesn't, but it can.)  It can even make it such that an attempt to copy the pointer triggers a fault.  It can also use the freed space to hold pointers to other bits of memory, for example.  To look at the freed data is 'undefined behaviour'.  What you find is entirely up to the implementation of `malloc()` et al.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *The OP does have business looking at the memory.* – please read what I wrote and don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @Swordfish: Your words are “you have no business looking at that memory through `q`.” That is a false statement. The OP does have business looking at that memory through `q`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The question is a bit ambiguously worded, and the lack of accompanying code does not help give context.  Based on the wording, though, I think your interpretation may be correct.

Comment: Stop the squabbling — it isn't helping.  And the program has no permission from the C standard to look at the freed data via `q` because it was freed.  What a particular implementation does in response to the attempt that is undefined behaviour according to the standard is a separate discussion — and may be the relevant discussion, but the implementation (o/s, library) should be defined because the answer will be specific to that combination.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: The question shows data before `free`, which contains all zeros in the allocated memory (except for an isolated byte) and a 33 before it, and the data after `free`, in which the previously allocated memory contains non-zeros. It is fairly clear that the memory allocation software wrote that new data. We certainly know the question is not asking why `free` did not clear the memory because the memory was not cleared—it did not transition from non-zero to zero, so that cannot be what the question was asking about.

Comment: Actually my question was about the new data that appeared after the free, I wanted to understand what does `112 132 178 223 255 127` rappresent, because it seems to be a common pattern among all the tests I have done on various machines. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The memory management software you are using uses the memory released by `free` for its own purposes. It needs data to organize the blocks of memory that are available for allocation, and using the memory released by `free` is a convenient way to do that.

How the memory is used, and whether it is used, is implementation-specific. One implementation may use the freed memory in one way, while another implementation uses it in another way, and a third implementation might not use the freed memory at all, at least for certain sizes of blocks. For example, blocks of a certain fixed size might be tracked by a bitmap maintained elsewhere, possibly using different bitmaps for different fixed sizes.

Comment: Alright, I was trying to understand how the memory manager organize the free blocks. I think that those numbers left when the memory is freed means something, but I can't find out what they rappresent.

Comment: @Ghimbo21: You should not expect to figure out what the numbers mean by examining them. It might be possible, but it might be very difficult, depending on the techniques used. The best way to understand what the numbers mean would be to get the source code or documentation for the `malloc` family of routines used in your C implementation and read it. Failing that, you could try reverse engineering the code from the object modules in the library. Either of those methods requires considerable knowledge and experience.